# Format dates on an entire column with ExcelWriter and Openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, date, openpyxl

I'm trying to write a pandas DataFrame to Excel, with dates formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD", omitting the time. Since I need to write multiple sheets, and I want to use some advanced formatting opens (namely setting the column width), I'm using an `ExcelWriter` object and `openpyxl` as engine.

Now, I just can't seem to figure out how to format my date column.

Starting with

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'string_col': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']})
df['date_col'] = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=3)
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, 'test', index=False)
```

This will write the dates as `2020-01-01 00:00:00`. For some reason I can't understand, adding `datetime_format='YYYY-MM-DD'` has no effect *if openpyxl is the selected engine* (works just fine if `engine` is left unspecified).

So I'm trying to work around this:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, 'test', index=False)
    writer.sheets['test'].column_dimensions['B'].width = 50
    writer.sheets['test'].column_dimensions['B'].number_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

The column width is properly applied, but not the number formatting. On the other hand, it does work applying the style to an individual cell: `writer.sheets['test']['B2'].number_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

But how can I apply the formatting to the entire column (I have tens of thousands of cells to format)? I couldn't find anything in the openpyxl documentation on how to address an entire column...

> Note: I could do:
>
> ```py
> for cell in writer.sheets['test']['B']:
>     cell.number_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
> ```
>
> but my point is precisely to avoid iterating over each individual cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are using `openpyxl` engine. But if you have flexibility to switch to `xlsxwriter`, you can use it as follows with help from [this documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_datetime.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'string_col': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']})
df['date_col'] = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=3)
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', datetime_format='YYYY-MM-DD') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, 'test', index=False)
    writer.sheets['test'].set_column('B:B', 50)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You're right, thanks! I didn't compare the capacities of all engines, but `xlsxwriter` does what I need (too bad `openpyxl` isn't keeping up on this one).

Answer (score 1):

You can treat your dates as a column of strings and slice it to get `'YYYY-MM-DD'`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'string_col': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']})

df['date_col'] = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=3)
df['date_col'] = df['date_col'].astype("str").str.slice(start=0, stop=10)

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, 'test', index=False)
    writer.sheets['test'].column_dimensions['B'].width = 50
```

Comment: But then the date is stored as a string in the Excel file (also `pandas.Series.dt.strftime` is probably a better option for such a conversion). If that's simply not possible, I'll raise that as a feature request.